# Where can I get xml/xsd schema of iCalendar specification RFC 2445 version 2.0.?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, icalendar

Currently I am working in ICalendar (.ics) file parsing and manipulation. I need to  make XML/XSD for the same. Where can I get full xml/xsd schema of iCalendar specification RFC 2445 version 2.0.?

Comment: The standard  rfc 2445 is a mime attachment to email (smtp) and is http (html) format not xml format.

Answer (score 0):

"xCal", an XML format for iCalendar data can be found at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6321

Note that RFC 2445 is obsolete (Replaced by RFC 5545 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545)